# First/last line/columns on cmd.exe

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Is there a way to NOT using first/last lines/columns on cmd.exe ? I have a string variable that contains more then 150+ character. I want to print on screen but without using first/last lines/columns and i dont want to change default mode con settings.

P.S. = If it can be done with pure batch i will be glad but not necessary.

**10/04/2014 Edit**

I have a string variable that contains more then 150+ character. As you know standart cmd.exe 80 columns. I want to start printing to screen from line number 1 to whereever its go but NOT using column number 1 and column number 80. Something like creating "text area"

Comment: You could use a for loop.  Type `for /?` to learn about it.

Comment: I didnt realy find out how can i done that. Can you show me a example ?

Comment: Edit your question and give examples about what you need to do.

Comment: I edited my question if you can look i will be glad. Something like:  imgur.com/L0To8Vj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set a=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa12345678bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb123456789cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc123456789dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

echo. %a:~0,78%&echo. %a:~78,78%&echo. %a:~156,78%&echo. %a:~234,78%
```

expand, if neccessary.

EDIT: or with a bit more elegance:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%i in (0,78,1000) do echo. !a:~%%i,78!|findstr ".."
```

the `findstr` prints only lines that have more than 1 char (every line will at least have one char, the leading space)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop.

`for /F "tokens=2-6* delims= " %%I in ("hey do you like batch files") DO (echo %%I %%J %%K %%L)`

The output is...

```
C:\>for /F "tokens=2-6* delims= " %I in ("hey do you like batch files") DO (echo %I %J %K %L )

C:\>(echo do you like batch )
do you like batch
```

Change `tokens` to skip more or less and to include more columns, but make sure the 6 is changed to the number of "columns" you have.

Change `delims` to use a different delimiter as the column separator.

Add additional `%%` variables to show more columns.

This works in batch and cmd files so if you want to run it interactively you need to change all the double %s to single.

As part of your learning exercise please read the `for /?`, `set /?`, and others as there is a lot of useful information in there and it is quite concise.